# Wrong Redirect/Rewrite Rules?

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm a total newbie to rewrite and redirect rules and i have some strange problems on my multisite.

when i try to open [www.my-website.com/blog](http://www.my-website.com/blog) or [www.my-website.com/xmas](http://www.my-website.com/xmas) for example, in safari browser everything works fine.

when i try to open that link in chrome or firefox i'll end up on the start page. but if i'm on the start page an try to open the link a second time, everything is doin well.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^presse/ https://www.my-website.com/kontakt/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^kompetenzen/Gesundheitsmarketing.html https://www.my-website.com/leistungen/gesundheitsmarketing/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^kompetenzen/ https://www.my-website.com/leistungen/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^news/ https://www.my-website.com/blog/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shared/ https://www.my-website.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ueber_uns/ https://www.my-website.com/ [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /de https://www.my-website.com/
Redirect 301 /impressum.html https://www.my-website.com/impressum/
Redirect 301 /karriere/index.html https://www.my-website.com/karriere/
Redirect 301 /leistungen/Promotion_Personalgestuetzte_Verkaufsfoerderung.html https://www.my-website.com/leistungen/promotion-live-und-digital/
Redirect 301 /?author https://www.my-website.com/

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

like i said, i'm a total newbie to htaccess stuff.

i hope someone can help me.

thank u very much :)

EDIT: i forgot the security headers

```
# Security Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self';"
    Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
    Header set Feature-Policy "geolocation 'self'; vibrate 'none'"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: There's nothing in your `.htaccess` file that would seem to do this. Also, the fact that you are seeing different behaviour in different browsers (and a 2nd request from the homepage "works") also suggests "something else" is going on. Different behaviour in different browsers strongly suggests a caching / cookie issue?

Comment: _Aside:_ You shouldn't be mixing redirects from both mod_alias `Redirect` and mod_rewrite `RewriteRule`. `Redirect 301 /de` redirects everything that simply starts `/de`, eg. `/deanything`. And what is `Redirect 301 /?author` supposed to be matching?

Comment: mhh.. that's really strange. i thought it would be a problem with my `.htaccess` file. i don't use any caching plugin at all :-/

Comment: Having you tried clearing the browser cache / cookies? Try a _new_ incognito session?

Comment: Presumably `/blog` and `/xmas` don't exist as physical directories or files? Is it just these specific URLs that are the problem, or are there others?

Comment: is it better to use the mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` instead of the Redirect 301 in my case?

Comment: yeah right. `/blog` and `/xmas` are just permalinks. it's on other permalinks too. I already cleared cache and cookies a few times :(

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite executes first, despite the order of the directives. So the WordPress front-controller is processed _before_ the `Redirect` directives. The `Redirect` directive is also prefix-matching. You can get unexpected conflicts. (Although I don't see any conflicts here. But `/?author` doesn't make sense.)

Comment: cool thanks :) with `?author` i tried to block the author page.. lol... now you know, that I'm a total newbie to this. by the way - i edited my question, because I forgot the security headers from my `.htaccess`file